# How to inject only the parameters that need special resolution using Unity?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

having the following classes and interfaces:

```
private class ClassToResolve
{
    public ClassToResolve(ConstructorArgument arg1, ConstructorArgument arg2, IConstructorArgument2 arg3)
    {
    }
}

private class ConstructorArgument
{
}

private class ConstructorArgument2 : IConstructorArgument2
{
}

private interface IConstructorArgument2
{
}
```

Imagine that I have the following registration:

```
UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

container.RegisterType<IConstructorArgument2, ConstructorArgument2>("A");
container.RegisterType<IConstructorArgument2, ConstructorArgument2>("B");

// How to register this?
container.RegisterType<ClassToResolve, ClassToResolve>(...

ClassToResolve result = container.Resolve<ClassToResolve>();
```

I'm trying a way to not have to usean InjectionContructor that forces me to put all the contructor arguments as this is becoming a nightmare on the project we are working as everytime dependencies change we have to modify lots of registrations.

In this case I would like to have a way to do something like: `container.RegisterType<ClassToResolve, ClassToResolve>(new ResolvedParameter<IConstructorArgument2>("arg3", "A");`

Is this possible with the UnityContainer or writting an extension to it?

Thanks.

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280170/why-do-we-need-abstract-factory-design-pattern

Comment: @daryal: nice post but this time I don't have problems with run-time data but with different registered names. I want to avoid writing all the constructor parameters just because one needs a name to be resolved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unity: Implicit ResolvedParameter for unnamed registrations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905504/unity-implicit-resolvedparameter-for-unnamed-registrations)