# How to register collections for injection

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I want to inject service1 to servicemanager1 and service2 to servicemanager2.
How can I do it using declarative approach (RegisterType or something similar)?

P.S. I don't want to use RegisterInstance, because real situation is more complex.

```
    container
        .RegisterType<IService, Service>("Service1", new InjectionConstructor("Service1"))
        .RegisterType<IService, Service>("Service2", new InjectionConstructor("Service2"))

        .RegisterType<IServiceManager, ServiceManager>("SM1")//Want to inject service1
        .RegisterType<IServiceManager, ServiceManager>("SM2")//Want to inject service2
        ;  

    container.ResolveAll<IServiceManager>();
```

...

```
    public class ServiceManager : IServiceManager
    {
        public ServiceManager(IService service)
        {
            Service = service;
        }

        public IService Service { get; private set; }
    }
```

Comment: What is the difference? Why you want to do that?

Comment: It's sample code for demonstration of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are registering your services with named registrations, then you just need to use `InjectionConstructor` parameters in your service managers. This way you can tell Unity to resolve the `IService` dependency using a specific named registration.

```
container
    //Register services as named registrations
    .RegisterType<IService, Service>("Service1", 
         new InjectionConstructor("SomeValueForService1"))
    .RegisterType<IService, Service>("Service2", 
         new InjectionConstructor("ADifferentValueForService2"))
    //Register service managers
    .RegisterType<IServiceManager, ServiceManager>("SM1", 
         //Resolve its IService dependency using a specific named registration
         new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IService>("Service1")))
    .RegisterType<IServiceManager, ServiceManager>("SM2",
         //Resolve its IService dependency using a specific named registration 
         new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IService>("Service2")));
```

Let's say your service class looks like this:

```
public class Service: IService
{   
    public Service(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public void Greet()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Greetings from " + this.GetType().FullName + ". Assigned name is " + _name);
    }
    private string _name;
}
```

Then you could get all the service managers and call the Greet method on the service:

```
container.ResolveAll<IServiceManager>().ToList().ForEach(sm => sm.Service.Greet());
```

> Greetings from Service. Assigned name is Service1Name
>
> Greetings from Service. Assigned name is Service2Name

You could also get a specific service manager, which will use the correct service:

```
container.Resolve<IServiceManager>("SM1").Service.Greet();
```

> Greetings from Service. Assigned name is Service1Name

You can check an example in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9S5sa0).

Comment: Thanks! But what if I want to "override" only one parameter of constructor?

Comment: For the other parameters you will need to provide resolvedParameters, but they don't need to be named registrations. So if your service manager constructor also requires an IFoo, you could add `new ResolvedParameter<IFoo>()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22030760/403256 - solution for unknown amount of parameters in constructor.